# Mapbox Static api - web services: Simple way to derive bounding coords from zoom ratio?

Tags: mapbox

Is there a simple way to derive the bounding lat/long coordinates from the Mapbox Static web services api?  For example, let's say I make a call to:

```
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/-73.99,40.70,13/500x300.png
```

I'm assuming pixel (x:250,y:250) should center around long: -73.99, and lat: 40.70.  How can I figure out what the lat and long values are at pixel (x:0, y:0)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [geo-viewport](https://github.com/mapbox/geo-viewport) library to do this - it converts bounding boxes to centerpoint & zoom combinations.